# The reason why the member variable of the node to be deleted from the doubly linked list should be initialized to null

Tags: java, null, doubly-linked-list

```
public class Node<E> {
    E data;
    Node<E> left;
    Node<E> right;
}
```

The code below deletes a node at a specific index from a doubly linked list. At the end of the code, left, right, and data of the node to be deleted must all be initialized to null. Is this a necessary process? What can happen if you don't initialize to null

```
public void remove(int index) {

    Node foundNode = findNode(index);
    Node leftNode = foundNode.left;
    Node rightNode = foundNode.right;

    leftNode.right = rightNode;
    rightNode.left = leftNode;

    foundNode.left = null;
    foundNode.right = null;
    foundNode.data = null;

    --size;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it helps garbage collector determine whether that allocated memory is to be freed, but not sure.

Comment: Exactly that, without it you have a memory leak.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Only if something else holds a reference to the node in question, otherwise GC will find a remove it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "normal" circumstances the three last assignments with `null` are not needed. When the function completes, its local variables are deallocated, and so there will usually not be any reference to the node that was referenced by `foundNode`.

However, it could be that in other code -- not part of this function -- there is still a variable that references that node, and then it is not that bad to indicate that this node is no longer part of a (longer) list. By setting `left` and `right` to `null`, the following invariant is maintained for every `node`:

1. Either `node.left == null`, or
2. `node.left.right == node`

...and similarly:

1. Either `node.right == null`, or
2. `node.right.left == node`

If we do not set `foundNode.left = null`, then the above invariant is not restored, and this could be an issue if there is still a reference to `foundNode` outside of the function's execution context.

As to `foundNode.data = null`: that should not really be necessary. If the node referenced by `foundNode` is not referenced elsewhere, then `foundNode` can be garbage collected. And if there is also no other reference to its data, then also that data can be garbage collected. Setting this property to `null` does not really change that process. Secondly, if we consider the case where there still might be a reference to this node, then `null` might be data that is *actually* meaningful in the overall algorithm, so setting it to `null` is not guaranteed to mark it in an unambiguous way as a "deleted" node.

Answer (score 0):

To be entirely clear: `new Node()` would initialize the node fields `left` and `right` with `null`.

That `remove` sets all fields of the removed `foundNode` to `null` is a **misguided** attempt to *optimize* garbage collection.

You do not create lingering objects (other removed nodes), no memory leak. As a garbage collector can deal with collections of unreachable objects.

Mind: for other languages this might not hold.